# Call async inside public static bool

Tags: c#, static

I wrote code about the settings page that uses static bool
then I need to Check If the public static bool changed or not In the form that I needed to call
(Form1 Is main form and Can be opened Once But Form2 Can open >1)
then I wrote this code

**Form1:**

```
    private static bool Called = false;

    public static bool HideButton
    {
        get { return Called; }
        set
        {
            if (Called != value)
            {
                Called = value;
                Update(); //function about updating buttons
            }
        }
    }
```

**Form2:**

```
private void checkBox5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (checkBox5.Checked) 
    { 
        Form1.HideButton = true; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Form1.HideButton = false; 
    } 
}
```

Then it said that you can't run non-static inside static
So I have an idea If I can check public static bool then call async void that is not static.
any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What does `async` have to do with any of this? Can you please [edit] the question and explain exactly why you need `HideButton` to be static? I'm assuming the error is at `Update();` because it's a non-static method. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `static` means *not instance*, so you have *one and only one* `Called` value for *all* `Form1` instances.
When you try to call `Update()` within `static` property `set`, the compiler complains: it doesn't know on *which*
instance should it be called (imagine, that there are *three* opened `Form1`).

You can either add some logic, e.g. let call `Update` on all opened `Form1`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static bool Called = false;

public static bool HideButton
{
    get { return Called; }
    set
    {
        if (Called != value)
        {
            Called = value;

            // Assuming WinForms  
            // We call Update on all opened Form1 forms
            foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>())
                form.Update(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Or you may let each `Form1` instance have its own `Called`, i.e. drop `static`:

```
private bool Called = false;

public bool HideButton
{
    get { return Called; }
    set
    {
        if (Called != value)
        {
            Called = value;

            Update(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Please, note, that [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) is quite a *different conseption* which is orthogonal to [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)